# Text goes out of Textfield - Flutter

Tags: flutter, constraints, overflow, textfield, behavior

So I have a textfield that is positionned in the center of a Container. My problem is the more I decrease the height of my screen the more the text of the textfiled goes out of the boundaries. I wrapped the textfiled with a container and gave it a color and it seems that the textfield is correctly adapting to the changes to fit the container but the Text or the input of the textfiled behaves on its own and goes out of the boundaries the more i adjust the height. Any solution ?

```
Column(
                                  mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                                  children: [
                                    Container(
                                      height: height * 0.076823398741207,
                                      width: width * 0.414674703803783,
                                      decoration: BoxDecoration(
                                        color: Color.fromARGB(212, 17, 19, 57),
                                        borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(20),
                                      ),
                                      child: Center(
                                        child: Row(
                                          children: [
                                            Expanded(
                                              child: TextField(
                                                style: TextStyle(
                                                  color: Colors.white,
                                                  fontSize: width *
                                                      0.0103928497193931,
                                                ),
                                                decoration: InputDecoration(
                                                  filled: true,
                                                  fillColor: Colors.red,
                                                  constraints: BoxConstraints(
                                                      minHeight: 120),
                                                  contentPadding:
                                                      EdgeInsets.only(
                                                    left: width *
                                                        0.0166285595510289,
                                                  ),
                                                  border: InputBorder.none,
                                                ),
                                              ),
                                            ),
                                          ],
                                        ),
                                      ),
                                    ),
)
```

[Sampel of the problem](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mfbZU.png)

I tried a lot of solutions such as wrapping it with a SingleChildScrollView, setting maxlines and minlines but nothing. The only thing that seems to change a little bit the behaviour of the text is setting maxHeight and minheight in the constraints of the InputDecorator of the textfield.

Comment: I'm not sure how to solve it, but my first impression of your code is that it seems weird to me to scale widths and heights like you do in your code. Using `Flexible` widgets to get the desired effect I think is more conventional. And the scaling of the font maybe with the help of `FittedBox` instead of scaling the fontsize

Comment: If you're talking about why do I use these values for the height and width it's because I'm using a Figma design and I want the app to look exactly like it. Flexible is a descent option and I worked with it before but sometimes it does not give you a lot of freedom or space to customize liek you want. Concerning FittedBox, can you please explain me more how to do it for the fontSize ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of giving `fontSize: width * 0.01...`, try doing like so in your `build` (or the context won't be accessible)

```
final cellHeight = MediaQuery.of(context).size.height / 100;
final cellWidht = MediaQuery.of(context).size.width / 100;
```

By doing so you create 2 variables that represent 1/100 of your screen width or height (responsive).
You can then multiply your `cellHeight` or `cellWidth` with the `fontSize` you prefer, grating the `fontSize` will be responsive.

```
Column(
 mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
   children: [
      Container(
         height: cellHeight * 8, <-- EXAMPLE
         width: cellWidth * 20, <-- EXAMPLE
         decoration: BoxDecoration(
            color: Color.fromARGB(212, 17, 19, 57),
            borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(20),
         ),
         ....
         child: TextField(
            style: TextStyle(
            color: Colors.white,
            fontSize: cellWidth * 7, <-- EXAMPLE
         ),
         decoration: InputDecoration(
         filled: true,
         ....
        contentPadding:EdgeInsets.only(
           left: 5 * cellWidth,  <-- EXAMPLE
        ),
        border: InputBorder.none,
       ),
      ),
     ),
    ],
   ),
  ),
 ),
)
```

Let me know if this solve your problem, if not, update your question with more details about what's wrong, happy coding!

Comment: Never thought about that before, Thanks !
But this doesn't fix the problem I'm facing, here is a better description:
When I reduce the height of my screen, the textfield adapts correctly, I know that because I gave it a filledColor, and it fills exactly the size of the container in which the textfield is contained but the issue is that the cursor or the input or the text ( call whatever you want) is blinking outside of the textfield, the input is not centered in textfield. The more I reduce the size of the height the more the input goes under the box where it's supposed to fit in.

Comment: Try removing the BoxConstrains and contentPadding. Try using Margin and Padding to acheive the same thing. Let me know!

Comment: I guess I found the solution. I need to set isDense to true in the InputDecoration widget. This fixed my problem and now the cursor or the input field correctly shrinks itself to the allocated space. Thanks for the tip given me earlier about the cellHeight and width and for helping me.

Answer (score 0):

The solution was to set `isDense` to `true` in the `InputDecoration`.